# What's the problem of always using QoS 0 in a MQTT session?

Tags: embedded, mqtt, iot, paho

I've been developing an always-connected MQTT client on a strictly resource constraint embedded device  using Paho C library. Here's my questions:

1. Apart from the broker and client crashes, Are there any other reasons for a QoS 0 message to not  arrive at the destination?
2. In a subscription request, is it possible that broker does not accept the requested QoS?
3. Under what circumstances could a QoS 1 message be received multiple times?

Comment: Don't assume MQTT will always run on TCP/IP

Comment: @hardillb Why? Isn't it required by the protocol/standard?

Comment: Read the spec http://docs.oasis-open.org/mqtt/mqtt/v3.1.1/os/mqtt-v3.1.1-os.html

Comment: @hardillb _"The protocol runs over TCP/IP, or over other network protocols that provide ordered, lossless, bi-directional connections."_ According to the spec, it's required the underlying protocol to be ordered, lossless and bi-directional. So, I think the only thing that may cause a message loss is an application layer fault. Am I right?

Comment: The original network the first ever MQTT sessions ran on used to lie (it would send ack messages from the local router, not the actual other end of the connection)

Comment: @hardillb Which ack? TCP's ack or MQTT's ack?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(1) A message delivered at QOS0 via TCP/IP is only guaranteed to have reached the remote machine's TCP stack not the actual application that is running (be that a MQTT client or MQTT broker).

Messages sent at higher QOS are acknowledged by the application not just the TCP/IP stack of the host machine so mean that you can be more certain it has actually been processed.

(2) Some brokers may only support QOS 0 or QOS 0/1 (e.g. [AWS IoT](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/mqtt.html)) and as mentioned in the [doc](http://docs.oasis-open.org/mqtt/mqtt/v3.1.1/os/mqtt-v3.1.1-os.html#_Toc384800440) the SUBACK message includes the QOS level that was granted which may not match what was requested. So even if the subscribing client

(3) If the client crashes having processed the message but before sending the PUBACK then the broker can try and deliver the message again when the client reconnects.